# Ubuntu 16.04 VirtualBox can't autoresize

Tags: virtualbox, 16.04, display-resolution

I have install Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox. Then i tried install Guest Additions from CD but it seems bad installation. So i install guest additions from `apt-get` and it seems like good installation.

Then i tried to do like described in this [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252920/how-to-get-ubuntu-vb-guest-to-use-monitors-native-resolution/252968#252968?newreg=2b2689ef8aaa4dcd8950db2f3ba8db60) and it doesn't help.

What i need to do to enable "Auto-size screen" item in menu of VirtualBox.

P.S. I can't use ubuntu on notebook, coz it has 1366x768 resolution, and ubuntu haven't this resolution.

Please help me! I trying to fix this trouble about week!

Comment: did you installed guest-additions on the guest OS?

Comment: yes, but i don't know is it installed properly

Comment: are you shure it need "-1" ? Coz i really can't do that!

Comment: i didnt set the "-1", a couple of questions, the host is Ubuntu 16.04? the guest is ubuntu 16.04?, which virtualbox version?

Comment: Host: Windows 7
Guest: Linux Ubuntu 16.04
VirtualBox: 4.3.6

Comment: Same problem on Windows 10 insider preview with Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtualbox 5.0.20 .

Comment: I installed `virtualbox-5.0` from the official website and couldn't get autoresize to work even with guest additions. So I purged the package, deleted `VirtualBox VMs` (had nothing useful in it) and `~/.config/VirtualBox`. Then I disabled secure boot using `mokutil` (needs reboot to be properly done). Finally,  installed `virtualbox-dkms` from the Ubuntu repositories. And to finish in greatness, installed a guest Ubuntu 14.04 with guest additions and autoresize worked. Yay!

Answer (score 5):

It works fine for me in with Win 7 host; IIRC it was a bit fiddly at first though. Really choppy UI. Doing the following fixed that for me:

But first: the latest VirtualBox 5.0.20. Perhaps an upgrade is in order? That also then gets you the latest Guest Additions. There is a variety of new stuff in Ubuntu 16.04, so that may make a difference.

Ok, so the issue is likely that guest addition drivers didn't compile correctly.

First, uninstall Guest additions, and purge them from the machine.

```
sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall
```

Second, install dkms. [They recommend installing that](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp46691715827040) before the Guest Additions are run.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Finally, install Guest Additions again:

```
sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Note: I've gotten into the habit of moving the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run to home directory, chmodding it to 755, and running it from there. I can't remember why; I think it might have been for a debian thing a while ago. I don't know if it makes any difference, but you might try it that way when you're doing the above steps:
(when you're in the cdrom dir)

```
cp ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run ~
cd ~
sudo chmod 744 ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

**Edit:**

Oh, another thing I did: After Guest Additions are installed, you can select its graphics adapter (not enabled by default).

Open Software & Updates, Additional Drivers tab, and under "InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH: BirtualBox Graphics Adapter", select "Using x86 virtualixation solution -X11 guest utilities from virtualbox-guest-x11 (proprietary)". Apply Changes, and reboot.

Comment: All this conclusion does not work.

Comment: My gues is 16.04.1. This worked for me! Except, the "other drivers" section shows two of those "Systemberatung"drivers. One with X11 in it, and other without. I know there is this thing happening where X11 is being replaced, but I don't even know if 16.04 made that leap. Graphics is working so much better than a few years ago, and haven't had to dig into xorg conf files for a long time now. So, I picked the non-X11 one and I can resize the desktop now.

Comment: After doing this (guest additions 5.2.12) i also had to enable 3D acceleration, see https://askubuntu.com/a/855360/300025

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and upgrading vbox to 5.1.2 and guest additions to 5.0.16 (and reinstalled them) solved it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)